# How can I estimate TL431 output voltage swings based on datasheet alone?

Tags: linear-regulator, frequency-response, step-response, tl431

I am trying to design a series-pass regulator that brings 12V down to 3.3V. If I see a 20 mA step change in current, I would like to stay within a certain output voltage range (±2%).

What parameters in the datasheet can help me figure this out? I see the stability boundary condition charts in [the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf) (p. 17, bottom left, for example) and understand how they work, but it's not clear to me how to characterize changes in the output voltage when a single step change load is applied or shed.

Any suggestions?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Can you use the tool (edit your question) and draw the circuit your describing?

Comment: Added one from LTSpice

Comment: Figure 12 on the datasheet may be of interest to you. Top left of page 17.

Comment: What is the change in voltage **across the TL431** and current **through the TL431** when the step change in load current happens?

Comment: @Hearth Is there a best practice for modeling a generic step response? Since an ideal step response happens infinitely fast, there must be a better way to model the load change that doesn't require complete guesswork, even if you're not sure of how fast the loads actually ramp up (as in, not happening infinitely fast).

Comment: It looks like you have created the circuit in LTspice. What does a simulation say?

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, It says I'm outside my 2% range slightly for a moment, but this simulation is only as good as the TL431 model.

Comment: @schadjo The step function is \$\frac{1}{s}\$ in the Laplace domain.

Comment: If you really care about a **step** change, or even just a fast change, in load current then you care about frequency-dependent behavior. This behavior will be very difficult to analyze precisely using just the datasheet values, so a good SPICE simulation might be your best hope. Remember that the graphs in the datasheet are **typical** behavior. And why are there no capacitors if you care about transient response?

Comment: You likely care about regulation *at those R4, R5 loads*. Between those loads and transistor/TL431 are trace or wire inductance & resistance, both in +3.3V line and its return. Bypass capacitors placed at the load(s) help smooth transient response as pointed out by @ElliotAlderson. Your simulation should include these reactances.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, Thanks for the insight. As far as caps, I had played around with different values and had gotten substantially different behavior depending on what TL431 model I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I see a 20 mA step change in current, I would like to stay within a certain output voltage range (±2%). What parameters in the datasheet can help me figure this out?

Nothing in the TL431 datasheet will tell you the load dip you will experience since the schematic you are using includes a BJT in the feedback loop.

If you were using the TL431 on it's own to provide a regulated supply, then there is information in the datasheet.
From the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf) you can calculate the change in Vout using the Total Dynamic Impedance. See Section 7.5 Note 2 and Figure 20.

If you were using JUST the TL431, then you expect about 13mV change for a 20mA change in output current (a 20mA change in I(ka)).

You have complicated your calculation by using a BC848 to buffer the output voltage. I assume you did this to reduce the idle or no load I(ka).

Given the circuit you have (with two 20mA loads shown):

1. At 40mA you are dissipating close to 350mW in the BC848 at 40mA Iout. **Far above its rating**.
2. The BC848 (assuming it survives) requires about 100mV change in V(be) for your 20mA change in Iout. This is about the worst case dip you would see in the output ….. about twice what you want to achieve.

Worst case you could then expect to see a 100mV drop in V(out) on the leading edge of the load change, and just a few mV droop as it settles.

To understand the system you have within the feedback loop you could do no better than to read [this analysis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280308828_Designing_with_the_TL431_-_the_first_complete_analysis) of the TL431 as an error amplifier by Ray Ridley.

If you want to reduce the transient dip on the output you have little choice but to add capacitance to the output rail. Once you have this capacitance (10uF+) in place the transient voltage drop is controlled NOT by the TL431 but by the storage capacity of the selected capacitor.
You could also IMO include a capacitor of about 1nF between the A and K terminal, and double the current to about 5mA.

Answer (score 2):

So, the worst-case step response, assuming the thing doesn't ring like a bell, can be had from the impedance of the common-base stage and the high-frequency impedance of the TL431 through it.

\$\frac{26\mathrm{mV}}{10\mathrm{mA}} = 2.6\Omega\$.  By figure 12 of the data sheet the TL431 has a high-frequency output impedance of 12\$\Omega\$ or so.  Assuming a \$\beta\$ of 60, the impedance at the base of your transistor should be 2.8\$\Omega\$.  A step change of 10mA should result in a step change of 28mV, which is a hair less than 1% of your 3.3V.

You might want to replace the TL431 with a fixed voltage on the base of your transistor and see what the step response is -- if it's too great, then the regulator has nothing to do with your troubles.

You might also want to determine if the actual current steps you'll be seeing are faster than the 1\$\mu\$s or so implied by the TL431's frequency response (unless your transistor is REALLY slow).

I think that if this were me, and I needed this to work with super sharp-edged current pulses, I'd have some capacitance on the output of the thing, with the circuit properly compensated so that it didn't oscillate.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Where is 26 mV / 10 mA coming from?

Comment: The small-signal emitter resistance of a transistor at room temperature is (emitter current)/(\$V_T\$), where \$V_T\$ is this complicated thing that depends on Boltzmann's constant and temperature, and is about 26mV at 300K.